# Error: Cannot find symbol variable when trying to establish imageviews

Tags: java, android

So I have an ImageView in my xml file that is an image I created. The id of it is gameplayTop. In my java file for that activity, I try to set a variable to set that imageview, but then when I start up my emulator it says "Error: cannot find symbol variable gameTop".

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ics466.brainscrew.GameplayActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <Chronometer
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gameplay_Area"
        android:src="@drawable/playarea"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/gameLeft"
        android:src="@drawable/gameplay_left_blue"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/gameTop"
        android:src="@drawable/gameplay_top_blue"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:maxHeight="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my javacode (with stuff cut out, but mainly I'm concerned with my imageview)

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class GameplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView top, bot, left, right;

    String message;
    private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    /**
     * Sets the screen layout and sets this screen to fullscreen-mode.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState saved previous state.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gameplay);

        top = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gameTop);

        Random rnd = new Random(2);
        int colorIndex = rnd.nextInt(8);
        makeBorders(rand4());

    }
```

Do I need to do something else to have it recognize the id?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Just tried to do so - cleaned the project, and when I went to rebuild it gave me the same error

Comment: Open the Gradle window on the right side of Android Studio and find the "lint" option. There is probably some other XML file that is misconfigured

Comment: UPDATE - after restarting and rebuilding and recleaning and resyncing my gradle stuff it finally worked. thank you??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Xml files, and make sure they are properly closed />